# Why Eigen doesn't need template keywords for using template function call of Matrix?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

MWE with c++17 and Eigen 3.4.0

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  Matrix<float, 2, 2> m;
  m << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0;
  m.cast<double>();
  // m.template cast<double>();
  return 0;
}
```

After reading Eigen document [TopicTemplateKeyword](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicTemplateKeyword.html) and
popular SO answer [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I kinda know why/when we need `template` keywords. However, now I don't understand why the code above doesn't emit error message when I forget use `template`:

```
m.cast<double>();
```

Looks like it matches each rule of "have to use template" in the Eigen document.

- `m` is a dependent name
- `cast` is a member template

Why Eigen doesn't force me to add `template` before calling `cast`?

My best guess is `m` might not be a real dependent name(I could be wrong). It would be nice if someone could show me the source code line. I feel this is a nice **FEATHER** and I wanna write similar code as an author so that makes my user's life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m` is not a dependent name.

You can only have dependent names **inside** of a template, if they depend on the template parameters of the enclosing templates.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
  Matrix<T, 2, 2> m; // Note that `T` has to be involved.
  m << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0;
  m.template cast<double>();
}
```